# EF order by property of navigation property?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a query that looks like this:

```
db.Items.Where(c => c.Enabled)
        .OrderBy(c => c.Vendor.Category.Select(b=> b.OrderPriority))
        .ToList();
```

I'm getting an error saying I need to implement `IComparable`... I'm not sure that I'm doing the right thing - I just want to order my items the `OrderPriority` property of `Category`. Is there any way to order using a property of a navigation property?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are trying to order `Items` by a collection of `OrderPriority`s. This is because a `Vendor` has multiple `Categories` (or may have, because it's a 1-n association).

I'm not sure if it is even possible what you're trying to express. If you want to order the `Items` by the highest `OrderPriority` found in one of its `Vendor`'s categories, you could do

```
db.Items.Where(c=>c.Enabled)
        .OrderBy(c => c.Vendor.Category.Max(b=> b.OrderPriority))
```